# IIS7 cannot verify access to path

Tags: iis-7, permissions

I've configured some sites on IIS pointing to E:\WebApps and subfolders. In basic settings when I click the Test Settings... button (connection as the application user) I get the error:

> The server is configured to use
>   pass-through authentication with a
>   built-in account to access the
>   specified physical path. However, IIS
>   Manager cannot verify whether the
>   built-in account has access. Make sure
>   that the application pool identity has
>   Read access to the physical path. If
>   this server is joined to a domain, and
>   the application pool identity is
>   NetworkService or LocalSystem, verify
>   that \$ has
>   Read access to the physical path. Then
>   test these settings again.

I've checked that my IIS is running as NETWORK SERVICE so I've given read, read and execute and list folders contents access to not only E:\WebApps but also to E:. But I still get the error. This machine is not part of a domain. Any ideas what am I missing?

I've tried putting a web.config in E:\WebApps, and restarting IIS and the site in particular, but it made no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't get the verification to work (anywhere else than in my workstation computer), but in the end I moved on and everything worked just fine, so maybe it wasn't that important.

Answer (score 0):

Please try: 1) Replace child folder permissions 2) web.config file is available in the folder e:\WebApps 3) Restart IIS.

Comment: What do you mean replace child folder permissions? And by putting a web.config, do you mean just dropping a blank one?

Comment: Yes, replace child folder NTFS permissions from Security -> Advanced option of folder permissions. Regarding placing web.config file, you need to have one with all basic website level setting in <system.webServer> tag.